# How to get the New(increase) FxCop warnings through command line?

Tags: .net, xml, cmd, fxcop, fxcopcmd

Does anyone have an idea , how would I get an xml or a html with just the increase in FxCop count.
Presently this is my fxcop cmd , where I replace {0} and {1} and create a batch file dynamically and run. 
I get the complete fxcop warnings although in the cmd prompt I can see it says the number of increase in fxcop warnings.

```
     fxcopcmd.exe /import:"c:\Standard.xml" /summary "/file:{0}" /searchgac /ignoreinvalidtargets /forceoutput /successfile /ignoregeneratedcode /saveMessagesToReport:Active 
    /r:-"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\Rules\NamingRules.dll"
     /r:+"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\Rules\DesignRules.dll"
     /r:+"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\Rules\GlobalizationRules.dll"
 /r:+"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\Rules\InteroperabilityRules.dll"
 /r:+"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\Rules\MobilityRules.dll"
     /r:+"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\Rules\PerformanceRules.dll"
     /r:+"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\Rules\PortabilityRules.dll"
     /r:+"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\Rules\SecurityRules.dll"
     /r:+"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\Rules\UsageRules.dll"
     /r:+"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\Rules\DataflowRules.dll"
     /r:+"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\Rules\MaintainabilityRules.dll"
     /r:+"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\Rules\ReliabilityRules.dll"
     /r:+"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\Rules\SecurityTransparencyRules.dll"
     /ruleid:-Microsoft.Design#CA1024 /ruleid:-Microsoft.Performance#CA1822
     /ruleid:-Microsoft.Usage#CA2227 
    /out:"{1}"
```

I was going to compare the Xml with a standard xml manually/XmlDiff and find the differences.
If the same is done by FxCop tool reliably , then I could use that.

Answer (score 0):

In order for FxCop to calculate the delta, it needs access to a report or project file in which the violations from the last report are stored.  Unless `{1}` is `c:\Standard.xml` (or gets copied to it before the next run), it doesn't look like your current command line will allow this to happen correctly.

Comment: Standard.xml is generated by FxCop previously.

Comment: If you update it with each run and/or also import the report from the last run, your delta counts should become accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution , `/saveMessagesToReport:Active` had to be changed to `/saveMessagesToReport:Absent` , This gave only the increase . Have to try more scenarios(same count but different results) and will update here.